# Primefaces 5.0 Chart Customization

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, charts, pie-chart

I have a problem with creating custom p:chart type="pie" canvases.

I have to change the background color of the pie chart like from white to another color.

I tried almost everything i found. I tried to override css resource of Prime Faces chart classes but it doesn't work. It turns all canvas/frame into one color and make chart disappears.

**.xhtml file**

```
<p:chart type="pie"
 model="#{dashboardController.model}"
 style="width:500px;height:250px;  margin: 0 auto;" />
```

**bean.java file**

```
model= new PieChartModel();
model.setDataFormat("value");
model.setShowDataLabels(true);
model.setFill(true);
model.setTitle("States");
model.setSeriesColors("62656a,a5a5a5,929397");
model.setShowDataLabels(true);
model.setDiameter(200);
```

This is the component which i need to change background of the canvas. You can see the same chart from here : http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/chart/pie.xhtml

**How can i change only the background? **

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `bg` on this class:

```
.jqplot-series-canvas {
  background:blue;
}
```

Comment: I had to modify `.jqplot-series-shadowCanvas` instead, because the entire series class was hiding some of my bars.